# как удалять сообщения определенного человека в вк

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Необходимо удалять сообщения определенного человека. Как я понял, нужно работать через методы messages.delete и execute. Желательно помочь с материалом.

Comment: А не лучше ли вместо этого пожарить картошечку с лучком и приправкой. Ко всему этому вкусненькое мяско. Ммм, это же намного лучше, чем удалять чьи-то сообщения

Comment: Желательно показать, что Вы уже сделали и что там не получается.